# How to make image opacity with css3

Tags: css

I am using below css to overlay transparency effect on image:

```
.banner-resources{
    background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    ),url('../img/Resources.jpg');

}
```

This is not working fine on IE8 and IE9. how can i make it work on ie8 and ie9?

Comment: Wait untill Thursday, and you won't have to worry about IE8 nor IE9.

Comment: Although IE9 should support multiple backgrounds it doesn't support CSS gradients.

Comment: Please remove the unrelated tags. This has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

They *(Gradients)* are not available for IE version 8 & 9. Also no multiple backgrounds in IE8. as per comment ***@Jon Koops***.

[image]

[Check this table.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)

Comment: Also no multiple backgrounds in IE8.

Comment: That i was about to mention but provided link can be used. for OP.